# How to add icons(or custom images) to right side of table view cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to add some icons to right side of a tableView cell. You can imagine it like "mute" icon of WhatsApp but it does not show icons in cells.
Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    let countryNames = Array(countryInfos.keys)
    content.text = countryNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    let myImage = UIImage(named:"star")
    cell.imageView?.image = myImage
    return cell
}
```

I tried like this also:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    let countryNames = Array(countryInfos.keys)
    content.text = countryNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    let myImage = UIImage(named:"star")
    cell.imageView?.image = myImage
    return cell
}
```

How can I make it visible and add it to the right side of a cell?

Current UI:
[image]

Expectation:
[image]

Note: star image is in the "Assets" folder as star.png

Comment: Can you attach an image of UI from the above code and also the expected UI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use custom cell and use stackView for text and image:

```
    class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var customLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    var customImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
    
    var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.alignment = .fill
        return stack
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(customLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(customImage)
        addSubview(stackView)
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    func setupConstraints(){
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

then you have to register the cell in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

and use it like so:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? CustomCell {
        cell.customLabel.text = countries[indexPath.row]
        cell.customImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "star")
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a CustomCell with XIB.
2. Use Label and Image, and give constraints
3. Use the CustomCell class in your Tableview.

Register your cell:

```
 YourTableViewName.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

Then use your CustomCell:

To access your CustomCell image, do:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     guard let cell = YourTableViewName.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()}
let myImage = UIImage(named:"star")
cell.imageView?.image = myImage
    return cell
}
```